# What causes these cracks on top of window corners?

Tags: windows, cracks

Today i suddenly saw this crack coming up in top corner of a window. I am curious to why such a thing happens. Is it normal or can be a sign of bigger problem like foundation issue??
Window is not difficult to open.
house is 4 year old and i am in NW arkanses where it has suddenly gone cold in last month

is this just a paint crack or dry wall crack and can we stop it from getting worse?
[image: crack on top of window corner]

Comment: "Is it normal or can be a sign of bigger problem like foundation issue?" Yes.

Comment: The type of construction we're looking at is fairly important to know. Please revise to add that, along with home age, location (climate), etc.

Comment: @FreeMan you just said yes.. i hope it was Yes to that its normal

Comment: Yes, it could be either. If the crack propagates farther, start suspecting some settling (or past settling cracks that weren't patched correctly). Note that minor settling is common and harmless. If it goes on, get an engineer to evaluate it. My century-old place was stabilized only after one corner was an inch higher than the rest -- but it _is_ now stable and if you can tolerate that tilt it's good for another century, despite having been thrown together as factory-worker housing.

Answer (score 2):

Those type of cracks are the result of normal expansion and contraction. Often they manifest as the weather gets colder. The normal solution is caulking with a flexible and paintable latex caulk and touching up with matching paint.